# How to define workflow to send mail on particular date?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-online

I have the **"Status of Mailer","E-mail"** fields on leads screen.I need to send mail after seven days for the particular mail address(Which is avail in Email field) after the **"Status of Mailer" field status change "Sent First Mailer"**.How to define this in Work Flow?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The best way is you has create two workflows, one when the lead change the status of "Status of Mailer" for "Sent First Mailer", when this happens you set a datetime field with the current date plus 7 days. And you can create another workflow that is launched when the datetime arrives in datetime field that you set plus 7 days.